# Why does parenting an element deform all of the vertices in Grease Pencil?

Tags: rigging, grease-pencil

I am trying to rig a 2D character I made in 2.8.  I separated the major pieces (which I was going to connect to a rig) into layers in the grease pencil.

I am using the human meta rig from which I deleted some bones.

However, as soon as I select one of these layers, and then click "parent", the entire GP layer immediately gets messed up (see pictures 1 and 2).

[image]

Turns into:
[image]

Can somebody explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you upload a .blend file - it may help to see exactly what is happening.

I've had similar issues with GP and rigging.  From what I understand, when you create a bone, or armature, they default with their own local axis (which point in a different direction to the world axis).  When you parent the Grease Pencil object to the bone, it inherits the object's local axis and flips, turns, or moves.

Possible Fix:
You can try adding a 90 or 270 to the rotation on that object to see if it comes back.

Future prevention:
As soon as you click on parent: armature with automatic weights (or something similar), there will be a small window that appears at the bottom left corner of the screen - you can click "Keep Transform" - this my prevent your geometry from getting away from you.

[image: "Keep Transform"]